# Why drawing a line in OpenGL is not working?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

```
GLfloat vertices[NUM_VERTICES][3] = {
    
{ -0.5, -0.4, 0.0 },
    {  0.5, -0.4, 0.0 },
    {  0.5,  0.4, 0.0 },
    {  0.0,  0.8, 0.0 },
    { -0.5,  0.4, 0.0 }
};
void init() {
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}

void display() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; i++) {
    
    glColor3fv(colors[i]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[i]);
    }
  glEnd();
  glutSwapBuffers();
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  //glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
  glColor3ub(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);        
  glLineWidth(10);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -0.4); 
  glVertex2f(0.0, 0.8); 
  glEnd();
}
```

I drew a pentagon using OpenGL. I want to draw a line from one point to another inside the pentagon but it doesn't work. How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glClear`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) clears the entire framebuffer and must be called once before drawing all of the geometry. If you call it in between, all previous drawings will be cleared. [`glutSwapBuffers()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) swaps the buffers and updates the display and must be called after drawing all the objects in the scene:

```py
void display() {
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; i++) {    
    glColor3fv(colors[i]);
    glVertex3fv(vertices[i]);
  }
  glEnd();
  
  glColor3ub(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);        
  glLineWidth(10);
  glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glVertex2f(0.0, -0.4); 
  glVertex2f(0.0, 0.8); 
  glEnd();

  glutSwapBuffers();
}
```